# Is there any advantage to using a specular map in combination with all the other maps in the metalness workflow?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, pbr

I have gathered online that there are typically two workflows applied when working with materials: A "Specular Workflow" and "Metallic Workflow". See this image that breaks down the metalness workflow (courtesy of Marmoset):

[image]

Is there any advantage to using a specular map in combination with all the other maps in the metalness workflow? Is this a viable way to work?

When creating PBR materials, I typically just use the **BaseColor** map, **Metallic**, **Roughness**, **Normal**, and **Displacement** (if necessary). These are the only maps I was taught to use in a PBR workflow.

However, some texture sets that I have downloaded online also include a Specular Map. There is a Specular channel in the Principled BDSF shader.

When should I use a map for it?

Hopefully this is a less open-ended way to phrase my question.

I am editing this question to be more specific and less opinion based.

Comment: You don't "have to", you can use maps if you want or not. It is up to you to get to the results you want through whatever means are necessary.

Comment: As long as metalness workflow is followed properly and its textures used, there shouldn't be any need for specular map, it's meant for a different workflow. More than that Blender's Principled was set up for metallness workflow and less - for specular (https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/t1cbbc/).

Comment: Zak, that was exactly what I needed to read. Thanks much for the link.